# how to read data from one column of datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to read data from one column of datagridview. My datagridview contains many columns but I want to read all cells but only from one column. I read all columns using this code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
        col.Name.ToString();
```

But I want to read all cell from particular column.

Comment: `foreach (var cell in col.Cells)` doesn't that work?

Comment: col doesn't contain a definition for Cells.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe this helps too. To get one cell:

```
string data = (string)DataGridView1[iCol, iRow].Value;
```

Then you can simply loop rows and columns.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms158656.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).

Comment: DataGridView1 doesn't contain a definition for item.

Answer (score 23):

Try this

```
string data = string.Empty;
int indexOfYourColumn = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
   data = row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Value;
```

Comment: @SumitGoyal: This code goes through every row, and reads the value from the specified column, which is what you asked for...

Comment: @yogi Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.ColumnIndex == 0) //Set your Column Index
                {
                //DO your Stuff here..
                }
            }
         }
```

or the other way

```
       foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                if (col.Name == "MyColName")
                {
               //DO your Stuff here..
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the clicked cell:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**FOREACH LOOP**

```
string data = string.Empty;
string data = string.Empty;
int indexOfYourColumn = 0;
int indexOfYourColumn = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
   data = row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Value;
```

**FOR LOOP**

```
using System.Collections;

string data = string.Empty;
int indexOfYourColumn = 0;

IList list = dataGridView1.Rows;

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
  DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)list[i];
   data = row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Value;
  data = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Value);
}
```